# Python 3.6 - BeautifulSoup4, parse table AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a table containing all the cities in California using bs4, but I am getting the below error

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I've tried using `find_all`, `findAll` (as suggested on other posts on this forum), but it's throwing the same error. From what I understand, I can't do that as my program return an object resultSet which is not iterable.

Also, I am not able to access the table `class="wikitable plainrowheaders sortable jquery-tablesorter"`, as it contains multiple class name, and when I run it omitting the `table_wiki_rows = table_wiki.findAll('tr')` it will return only the first line of the table 400+ time.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

## Python 3.6
##BeautifulSoup4
def get_all_cities(html_soup):
    """Scrape WIkipedia page for cities in California (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_California)
    and returns a structured list of city names, county, population, area, and incorporation date"""
    cities_in_california = []
    table_wiki = html_soup.findAll('table', attrs={"class":"wikitable"})
    table_wiki_rows = table_wiki.findAll('tr')
    for rows in table_wiki:
        table_rows_header = html_soup.findAll('th')
        table_rows = html_soup.findAll('td')
        city_entry = {
                'City_name' : table_rows_header[0].text,
                'City_type' : table_rows[1].text,
                'County' : table_rows[2].text,
                'Population' : table_rows[3].text,
                'Area_sqr_miles' : table_rows[4].text,
                'Area_sqr_km' : table_rows[5].text,
                'Incorporation_Date' : table_rows[6].text                
                }
        cities_in_california.append(city_entry)
    return cities_in_california

html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_California')
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
city_list = get_all_cities(html_soup)

df = pd.DataFrame(city_list )
df.head(7)
```

### EDIT - Working Code for reference

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

## Python 3.6
##BeautifulSoup4

def get_all_cities(html_soup):
    """Scrape WIkipedia page for cities in California (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_California)
    and returns a structured list of city names, county, population, area, and incorporation date"""
    cities_in_california = []
    table_wiki = html_soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders sortable'})
    table_wiki_rows = table_wiki.findAll('tr')
    for rows in table_wiki_rows:
        table_rows_header = rows.findAll('th')
        table_rows = rows.findAll('td')
        if len(table_rows_header) > 0 and len(table_rows) > 0:
            city_entry = {
                    'City_name' : table_rows_header[0].text,
                    'City_type' : table_rows[0].text,
                    'County' : table_rows[1].text,
                    'Population' : table_rows[2].text,
                    'Area_sqr_miles' : table_rows[3].text,
                    'Area_sqr_km' : table_rows[4].text,
                    'Incorporation_Date' : table_rows[5].text                
                    }
            cities_in_california.append(city_entry)
    return cities_in_california

html = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_California')
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
city_list = get_all_cities(html_soup)

df = pd.DataFrame(city_list)
df.head(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html_soup.findAll('table', attrs={"class":"wikitable"})` will return a list of all tables with a `class` value of `wikitable`. You can't call `.findAll` on such a list.

The data resides in a table that has multiple `class` attributes:

```
class="wikitable plainrowheaders sortable"
```

So, use this instead of just "wikitable":

```
html_soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable plainrowheaders sortable'})
```

Using `html_soup.find('table', attrs={"class":"wikitable"})` won't work, either, because there's another table before the main data table. Since that's the first one, using `find` will retrieve that and not the main table.

**Edit:**

The problem is with these two lines:

```
table_rows_header = html_soup.findAll('th')
table_rows = html_soup.findAll('td')
```

For each iteration of the loop, you're assigning all the `th` and `td` elements found inside the entire `html_soup` object. You should be using this instead:

```
table_rows_header = rows.findAll('th')
table_rows = rows.findAll('td')
```

Comment: Hey @Mahesh, thanks for your answer. I've actually restarted Spyder and my code works. Though, I am still getting 400 + time the first row without the city name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had some difficulties visualizing how the data were structured in once the table was scrapped. Really appreciate your help. :)